# League of Legends low FPS on GTX 750 TI?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have a GeForce GTX 750 Ti, and when I play League of Legends, I get very poor FPS.

FPS sits between 40-60 with medium settings, but I can actually play Battlefield 4 and Dirt Rally at high settings with 60 FPS.

I don't understand why I can't run League of Legends any better. I have all my drivers up to date.

Comment: This is actually a good question, as sometimes during different patches LoL acts up and performs worse

Comment: @Oak yeah, but it's low quality.

Comment: @r3pear "Low Quality" is an auto-block which prevents you from posting the question at all. Being able to edit it into something pleasant to look at isn't really a feat of genius either. I've edited the question, and wouldn't mind you linking to a definition of what "Low Quality" is in your context.

Comment: @user1337 WTF MAN?! IS QUESTION WAS SPECIFIC FOR LOL. AND YOU EDIT IT TO MAKE IT HILARIOUS.

Comment: 60fps in BF4 on high seems like a stretch to me with that card, but LoL should run smoothly.

Comment: I doubt this is the problem, but what is your CPU? Upgrading my GPU did jack to boost my fps (i went from a gt215 to a gtx980) so cpus are important to keep in mind

Comment: I dunno who the guy that edited was but, Jesus it has nothing to do with the original question

Comment: @Oak Was the original question not about the cause/solution of performance drops in League of Legends?

Comment: I agree with @Oak. Based off the original post, I am not confident that this was the original intent of the asker. The comment on the edit gives me the impression that it was made as a 'best guess' of what the asker wanted. If we can not say with absolute confidence, either based off what is in the original post or extra comments made by the asker, we should not be guessing the authors intent. If it is wrong, you will not help the asker. If the asker comes back, they are free to inform us of their intent, and we can reopen (or simply not close - 1 vote remaining at present) the question.

Comment: As such, I have reverted the rollback. **The asker could be meaning to ask a similar question**. I interpret "Why is it that I can run Battlefield 4, but not League of Legends", but not confidently enough to push it as an edit. One might argue that the rolled back question would cover this, but under the same grounds I would VTC the rolled back question as "too broad".

Answer (score 2):

This [support page](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/201752684-Low-Frame-Rate-FPS-Troubleshooting) has a list of troubleshooting ideas for improving League of Legends performance.

If I have to choose one of the eleven choices at random I'd choose **repair corrupt game files.**

> Occasionally, FPS problems can be caused when certain game files become corrupt. Using the repair function in the game launcher (the first window that appears when you run League of Legends) will fix any corrupted files.
>
> To run the repair function:
>
> - Run League of Legends.
> - Click on the "?" icon that is located in the top right corner of the window.
> - Click Repair.
> - Wait. The repair function can take anywhere from 5 minutes to over 30 depending on the number of corrupt files it has to repair.